# how I can separate nickel and chrome in single

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, chemical-engineering

How I can separate chrome and nickel from a nickel sulphate,nickel chloride and chrome salt separately??when these mixed up in a single solution.Please tell me how to do it using simple house hold items that does not cost too much. Please any one can help me as I am new to this field of chemistry.

Ok let me explain what happened. I want to do some electroplating. So for that I need chemicals to do nickel and then end chrome plating. I asked a guy in other city to send me chemicals that need for plating. He sent the chemicals but he used low grade packing that didn't survive the journey by general mail as in general mail they use very rough handling. So all mixed up but some did remain save and don't how eact quantity mixed up as parcel with torn from different places and it was some what losing it contents.

The parcel was containing nickel sulphate, nickel chloride and chromic salt. So i don't want to through away expensive chemicals with trying to save much as possible damage happened due to negligence of my supplier.

Comment: Provide more context to your question. // People with need to separate nickel and chrome in solution are seldom limited to household stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering this question, it would be useful to know the nature of the "simple house hold items" that may be used to get to the goal : separate nickel $\ce{Ni^{2+}}$ and chromium $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ ions. Because I am afraid this separation is not possible with "simple" products.

The usual method for analyzing these ions require the following steps. First a solution is made with about $0.4$ g of the initial solid mixture  dissolved in $20 - 30$ mL water. Add $\ce{NH3}$ solution up to pH $8 - 10$. Add then a solution of colorless ammonium sulfide $\ce{(NH4)2S}$ (or sodium sulfide $\ce{Na2S}$) in feeble excess. Heat to boiling in a hood : odor ! Filtrate on paper. Nickel and Chromium make a precipitate of $\ce{NiS}$  and $\ce{Cr(OH)3}$  which remains in the filtrate.  Forget about the filtrate.

Add $5 - 15$ mL of $2$ M $\ce{HCl}$ to the precipitate. Stir the mixture for one minute. Filtrate the whole : Nickel ions remain unsolved as a precipitate. Chromium hydroxyde $\ce{Cr(OH)3}$ is dissolved as $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ ions. This allows the separation of nickel and chromium. This is probably the goal of the present message.

If the experimenter wants to prove that the last precipitate contains nickel, and that the solution contains chromium, more selective tests must be done. But more complicated chemicals must be used.

To prove that nickel is in the precipitate, one should add $4 - 6$ drops concentrated nitric acid $\ce{HNO3}$, then heat at boiling temperature. This transforms $\ce{NiS}$ into $\ce{Ni^{2+}}$ ions. Take a small part of the obtained solution And add enough $2$ M $\ce{NH3}$ solution to get a basic pH. Add a couple of drops of dimethylglyoxime $1$% in ethanol. A red precipitate is produced if the solution contained nickel.

To prove the presence of $\ce{Cr}$ in solution, some $2$ M $\ce{NaOH}$ has to be added to the solution. Filtrate the greenish precipitate containing $\ce{Cr(OH)3}$. Take a small part of the precipitate. Add $2$mL $2$ M $\ce{NaOH}$ and $0.5$ g $\ce{PbO2}$. Heat to boiling temperature. Dilute with $10$ mL water. Acidify with $2$ M $\ce{H2SO4}$. Add then a few drops of diphenylcarbazide $0.2$% in ethanol. A purple reaction proves the presence of chromium.

Comment: Common household ammonia would possibly quantitatively precipitate Cr[OH]3 while maintaining Ni++ in solution as the ammonia complex. Another messier possibility is to oxidize Cr+3 to chromate with bleach and peroxide in base and filtering off nickel hydroxide [must check the potentials first] Reduce the chromate back with honey [invert sugar glucose + fructose both reducing sugars] and vinegar.

Comment: Or you could use vodka to reduce the chromate. Those household chemicals have much potential.

Comment: can i uses sodium carbonate to react with nickel sulphate to from ppt and then can filter that out????

Comment: Adding a carbonate ion to a solution made of both $\ce{Ni^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ ions will produce a mixed precipitate made of a mixture of nickel carbonate and chromium hydroxyde. Nickel and Chromium are not separated with this method.

Comment: @jmchemist. You are right. Thank you for the idea.  It is possible to separate nickel and chromium with ammonia $\ce{NH3}$. Adding ammonia to a solution contiaining both ions $\ce{Ni^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ will produce a precipitate of $\ce{Cr(OH)3}$ and a solution containing the blue and soluble $\ce{[Ni(NH3)6]^{2+}}$ ion.

Comment: can i use ammonia chloride in the reaction or i have to get pure ammonia as it's expensive here in my country

Comment: Chromium ions will not react with ammonium chloride or any ammonium ions origin to produce chromium hydroxide. But chromium ions do react with hydroxide ions $\ce{OH-}$ that are present in ammonium salt solutions if some $\ce{NaOH}$ has been added to the $\ce{NH4Cl}$ containing solution.

Comment: can i use NaOH in solution to ppt both but u guys might know that chromic salt will dissolve with excess NaOH while Nickel sulphate will remain undissolved. Am I right here?????

Comment: @Naveed AA. Yes. $\ce{NaOH}$ in solution makes a precipitate of $\ce{Cr(OH)3}$ with Cr salts. This precipitate is soluble in an excess of $\ce{NaOH}$ with formation of sodium chromite $\ce{NaCrO2}$. So an excess of $\ce{NaOH}$ in a solution containing both $\ce{Ni^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ produces a precipitate of $\ce{Ni(OH)2}$ without chromium. Filtration allows a separation of the ions. The precipitate may be filtered and should first be washed by a $\ce{NaOH}$ solution before using water. When diluted,  the chromite gets partly hydrolyzed and transformed back into $\ce{Cr(OH)3}$.

Comment: I think it much very cheaper then Ammonia right????

Comment: I don't know the prices of soda and ammonia

Comment: How much  NaOH do i need for 2.3kg of Nickel sulphate and nickel chloride (2.2+1.1KG).Chromic acid around 1.1KG

Comment: First remark : What is the meaning of "nickel chloride (2.2+1.1KG)". Is it equal to 3.3 kg nickel chloride ? Second remark : Chromic acid is not a salt of chromium. Chromic acid can be $\ce{H2CrO4}$ or $\ce{CrO3}$ or $\ce{H2Cr2O7}$. These substances are not chromium salts. Whatever the formula used, they do not produce $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ ions in water. So they do not react with $\ce{NaOH}$ or ammonia $\ce{NH3}$ as described previously. They do not produce a precipitate with both reagents ($\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{NH3}$). If you add $\ce{NaOH}$ to your mixture, nickel will precipitate alone.

Comment: sorry i mean 2.3 kg nickel sulphate and 1.1kg of nickel chloride

Comment: I rewrite your question : *How much NaOH do I need for destroying 2.3 kg of Nickel sulphate and 1.1 kg nickel chloride. Chromic acid around 1.1 Kg*  Your mixture contains 2300/154 = 14.9 mol $\ce{NiSO4}$ and  1100/129 = 8.53 mol $\ce{NiCl2}$. In total 23.43 mol nickel. To destroy it, the double (in moles) of NaOH is necessary, so 46.86 mol, which weighs : 46.86 mol x 40 g/mol = 1874 g $\ce{NaOH}$. To obtain this final value, the nickel salts have been calculated as anhydrous compounds, which is a special supposition, as the commercial substances are hydrates with 7 or 6 $\ce{H2O}$.

Comment: pls not to bother you. Can u write in KG how much NaOH in total?

Comment: $1874$ g NaOH is $1.874$ kg NaOH

Comment: pls tell how much water do i need to dissolve 100g NaOH???

Comment: At $0$°C, the maximum solubility of $\ce{NaOH}$ in water is $42$ g in $100 g$ water. So to dissolve $100$ g $\ce{NaOH}$ you need a minimum of $238$ g water. Personally I would need a little more, at least $250$ g water.